# Magento 2 - How to manage duties?

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

Is there any reason that in **Magento 2 we don't have Duty as additional totals row?**

We would like to start an e-commerce store which will ship goods to all countries around the world. It means we will need to calculate taxes and duties.

For taxes, we have all admin management tools, where we can define tax rates, tax rules etc. but for duties there is nothing.

Maybe there is a different way to configure duties in Magento 2? I will appreciate your answers and user cases how you have solved it in your projects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lukasz, please let me know how you solved the duty part of your ecommerce?

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer this Link**:- [Tax-Rule Configuratioin](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-tax-rules-magento-2.html). This is Really help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a prebuilt way to calculate duties and taxes in Magento 2. However, there are third parties that can.

I am with Zonos and we offer duty calculations and other cross-border solutions for Magento/Magento 2.

A few duty solutions for Magento that Zonos offers

1. [Zonos Checkout](https://marketplace.magento.com/iglobal-zonos-hello.html), full global checkout inclusive of calculating duties on your products, translation and more.
2. [Zonos Hello](https://hello.zonos.com/) offers **free** duty and tax estimations for the shoppers as they shop your website.
3. Zonos Duty and Tax for Magento Checkout is tied into the [Zonos Landed Cost API](https://docs.zonos.com/development/landed-cost-api)

Feel free to reach out to our team inquire@zonos.com if you have any questions on what you find on the Magento App store.